# restrict, no action & set default in ondelete optional parameter for fields

Tags: odoo

I am learning about optional parameter regarding fields for **ondelete** parameter.
These are the predefined values: "cascade", "set null", **"restrict", "no action"**, "set default"

Can anyone explain in detail about the

- difference between RESTRICT and NO ACTION.
- how SET DEFAULT is used in OpenERP 7?

  - where to set default value for the field ?
  - how to define set default value in python code itself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take for example a `Course` with `Student`s. On `Student`s is a foreign key to `Course`.  The `ondelete` determines what happens with the `student_id` column (on `Course`) when the `Student` is deleted.

- CASCADE: Delete the `Course` record with matching `student_id` when `Student` is deleted
- RESTRICT: Cannot delete the `Student` as long as it is related to a `Course`.
- NO ACTION: similar, but is a deferred check: You can delete the `Student` but you have to make sure that the integrity is OK when the transaction is committed.
- SET DEFAULT: uses openerp default definition (see `_defaults` dict in the python model definition)
- SET NULL: when a `Student` gets deleted, the `student_id` becomes `NULL` in the DB.

In Python you can find these in `_columns` defintion:

```
_columns = {
    'student_id': fields.many2one(
        'my.student',
        'Student',
        ondelete='set null',
    ),
```

Comment: what is the default if i did not set it?